# Can starting with: "The bottom line is" be considered redundant if the reader can clearly see that's, in fact the bottom line

Tags: phrases, expressions

My questions is, can the expression "the bottom line is" be considered redundant in an example like so:

> "[A long, detailed text or answer.]
>
> The bottom line is, it doesn't really matter."

Would it be appropriate to rewrite the last sentence in a more compact way e.g.

> So, it doesn't really matter.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: The bottom line is, saving three words doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's no worse than leading off a news broadcast with "Today's top story..." is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking that *the bottom line* means the last line of text? It does not.

*The* *bottom line* is, per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottom+line):

> the most important part of something; the most important thing to
>   consider

It derives from *the bottom line* in a financial sense--the bottom line represents the sum of total of assets. You certainly could replace this with *so*--grammatically speaking, either works. But the meaning is different.

*So* simply means "therefore," and does not assign the same value to a conclusion that *the bottom line* does. Granted, speaking casually, people probably do use them interchangeably.

But *the bottom line* is definitely not redundant because it is the last line of text. This expression may just as likely appear in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements are equivalent in meaning, and it is a matter of style to use one over the other. Often times, it is a good idea to sum up your arguments in a concluding sentence, so this is not necessarily redundant.